# EXTJS Grid row coloring failed

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, grid, extjs3

I am using extjs 3.2. I just tried one sample for grid row coloring with reference to http://skirtlesden.com/articles/styling-extjs-grid-cells. added grid view config in gridExample.js file which is holding static gird.,

```
    viewConfig: { 
    stripeRows: false, 
    getRowClass: function(record) { 
        return record.get('age') < 18 ? 'child-row' : 'adult-row'; 
    }
```

and added CSS in html page.

HTML code is,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>success</title>
<link href="/testing/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/testing/ext/resources/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
.child-row .x-grid-cell { 
    background-color: #ffe2e2; 
    color: #900; 
}  
.adult-row .x-grid-cell { 
    background-color: #e2ffe2; 
    color: #090; 
}
</style>
<script src="/testing/ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script src="/testing/ext/ext-all.js"></script>
<script src="/testing/JS/gridExample.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But grid row color not changed. Most of forums sure about code. So, is it any problem with css in html page?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext 3.x uses CSS classes of the form `x-grid3-...` for grid elements.
You can inspect [this 3.2 example](http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-3.2.0/examples/grid/array-grid.html)'s markup to see for yourself.

So, your CSS should be:

```
.child-row .x-grid3-cell { 
    background-color: #ffe2e2; 
    color: #900; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `!important` to those properties to get something similar to work.

```
.child-row .x-grid-cell { 
    background-color: #ffe2e2 !important; 
    color: #900 !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response kevhender. not worked. I tried this before itself.
"!important" it says; that 'this is important, ignore subsequent rules, and any usual specificity issues, apply this rule!'

Comment: Are you positive that the class is being applied to the row?  Have you confirmed this via inspection?

Comment: yep i am positive. I used debugger, and class assigned to every row. but no change in color :(
is it any possibilities with Extjs 3.2 version problem? coz http://skirtlesden.com/articles/styling-extjs-grid-cells is mentioned extjs 4